# Alignment missing in android multiplescreen style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

The below style i wrote in values>style.xml

```
<style name="phoneLetters">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

I have added textSize 12sp to 22sp for bigger appearance in tablet - values-sw600dp>style.xml

```
<style name="phoneLetters">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
```

Above styles marginLeft and garvity are missed in tablet. Should we duplicate above styles to here tablet styles also?

Comment: If you want the same effect in the tablet as well, definitely.

Comment: Is that wont take from the default values>style.xml? Otherwise there will be more duplicates?

Comment: Only one 'styles.xml' will be read from your resources, depending on the device type. default styles.xml will be read only if the device is not of the type sw-600dp

Comment: I dont think so. Because i have mentioned background color only in values>style.xml. Then how im even able to see the color in tablet-sw600dp? As per your point only one styles will apply, how it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a style duplicate there will be no problems, but you must add it in different folder in **res** for different screen resolutions.

For example if you have a style like this:

```
<style name="phoneLetters">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

You need to create a styles.xml whit the code above in:

- values
- values-small
- values-small-portrait
- values-small-landscape
- values-normal
- values-normal-portrait
- values-nomral-landscape
- values-large
- values-large-portrait
- values-large-landscape
- values-xlarge
- values-xlarge-portrait
- values-xlarge-landscape

After you add styles change for example text size **12sp** for small set **12sp** , for normal set **16sp** for large put **20sp** and you will see the difference from a device to another whitout doing anything. The textsize will be smaller on smartphones and bigger on tablet.

Hope this will help.

Cheers,